# Not able to use C++14 features( bind,lambdas,etc and getting C++11extension warning) after installing gcc49?

Tags: c++, osx-mavericks, c++14, gcc-warning, llvm-gcc

It shows that gcc49 is active:

```
$ port select --list gcc
Available versions for gcc:
    mp-gcc49 (active)
    none
```

but version is still 4.2.1,

```
$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

How do i fix this?

Comment: Have you tried compiling with `-std=c++14` parameter, sir?

Comment: `--with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1` doesn't look right

Comment: Most likely an issue with your `$PATH` (check `which gcc`). Make sure `/opt/local/bin` comes before `/usr/bin` (or possibly `/usr/local/bin`).

Comment: how do i compile with -std=c++14  .... i use 'make filename.cpp'?

Comment: $PATH is fine,molbdnilo.../opt/local/bin is before /usr/bin

Comment: @vedaanta If you're using a Makefile, then you should paste it in your question so we can tell you if it is correct or not. Anyway, your Makefile should contain a line like `CXXFLAGS= -std=c++14`

Comment: @Unda will keep that in mind from now on.....but do i need to write that long line to compile every time??

Comment: Write it only once in your Makefile, then just use 'make' and that will do.